# Scala - Filter lines in a document if a string/word is present

Tags: scala, filter

I have the following file called weblogs.txt:

```
56.38.234.188 – 99788 "GET /KBDOC-00157.html HTTP/1.0" …
56.38.234.188 – 99788 "GET /theme.css HTTP/1.0" …
203.146.17.59 – 25254 "GET /KBDOC-00230.html HTTP/1.0" …
221.78.60.155 – 45402 "GET /titanic_4000_sales.html HTTP/1.0" …
65.187.255.81 – 14242 "GET /KBDOC-00107.html HTTP/1.0"
```

And I would like to filter all lines which the word: "KBDOC"

This is what I have written so far, but without result:

```
val patt = "KBDOC".r
val kbreqs = sc.textFile("weblogs.txt").filter(line => line.contains(patt))
kbreqs.foreach(println)
```

But this print nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Expected result:

```
56.38.234.188 – 99788 "GET /KBDOC-00157.html HTTP/1.0" …
203.146.17.59 – 25254 "GET /KBDOC-00230.html HTTP/1.0" …
65.187.255.81 – 14242 "GET /KBDOC-00107.html HTTP/1.0"
```

Edit based on Solutions [Solved]:

```
val patt: String = "KBDOC"
val kbreqs = sc.textFile("weblogs.txt").filter(line => line.contains(patt)).collect()
kbreqs.foreach(println)
```

Comment: The println command is run on the executors, not on spark master. If you want the lines to be printed out in master, you must `collect()` them before.

Comment: sc.textFile("weblogs.txt").filter(line => line.contains(patt)).collect() like this??

Comment: Yes. Although, I wouldn't recommend doing this if your output may exceed available memory (since everything is loaded inmaster memory  on `collect`).

Comment: Thank you, Im just following some tutorials to learn so the documents are really small, no more than 10 lines. However I will keep your recommendation in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a `String` instead of a `Regex`:

```
val patt: String = "KBDOC"
val kbreqs = sc.textFile("weblogs.txt").filter(line => line.contains(patt))
```

Or if you'd like to use `Regex`:

```
val patt: String = ".*KBDOC.*"
val kbreqs = sc.textFile("weblogs.txt").filter(line => line.matches(patt))
```

Another version:

```
val patt: Regex = "KBDOC".r
val kbreqs = sc.textFile("weblogs.txt").filter(line => patt.findAllIn(line).length > 0)
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks, just some format issues with char "-" that is represented weird in the console, but that is not part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are mixing the regex with a method which expects a String as an argument.

Both `contains` and `matches` methods of `String` takes another `String` as a parameter which is then converted to a regex and finally matched against the String itself.

So, you can use any of the following

```
val s = """56.38.234.188 – 99788 "GET /KBDOC-00157.html HTTP/1.0""""

val pattern1: String = "KBDOC"
s.contains(pattern1)
// true

// Or,
val pattern2: String = ".*KBDOC.*"
s.contains(pattern1)
// true

// Or,
val pattern3: String = ".*KBDOC.*"
s.matches(pattern3)
// true

// but this will be false
val pattern4: String = "KBDOC"
s.matches(pattern4)
// false
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I completly new in Scaal. However still nothing is printed out. I think the issue (besides what you already pointed out) may be in the double quotes present in each line of the file, is it possible that " " may be causing anothe problem?. I see in your example you solved using the """ ... """

Comment: that will not be a problem for you... as your code will be reading these strings from the file.

Comment: Uhm I added an edit in the post, trying to follow your recommendations, but still nothing is print. Did I understand wrong or still some other changes are needed. Thanks!